# Error al guardar datos después de registro de usuario en Nodejs y MongoDB - ApiRest

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy haciendo un registro de usuario con Método post en Nodejs de la siguiente manera:

```js
const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
})
```

Al registrar el usuario me devuelve el id de la colección y lo almaceno en una constante "user", luego de eso quiero guardar los datos en la coleccion "Information" como me muestra en el código pero al probar con postman no guarda ningun datos, solo sigue cargando como si estuviera en un bucle infinito.

```js
user.save((err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      const user = user._id //Capturo el id del usuario que se registro en la base de datos
      
      const information = new Information({
          user: user,
          age: null,
          address: 'null'
      })
      
      console.log(information) //Hasta esta linea de codigo normal me muestra los datos de la colección "Information"

      information.save((err, information)=>{ //Pero en este punto no me funciona la funcion "information.save()" 
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
          console.log('Información guardada correctamente')
        }
      })
    }
```

Alguien podría explicarme ¿A qué se debe? que estoy haciendo mal?, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Si quitas todo lo que viene despues de `information.save` y lo dejas así `information.save()`, funcionaría, si quieres mantener el resto, lo tienes aquí abajo.

Ejecutala sincrónicamente. Es tan facil como escribir **async** antes de los parámetros de `user.save`

```js
User.save(async (err, user) => {...}
```

Y posteiormente en `information.save` añades **await**. Y ya debería funcionar

```js
await information.save
```

Comment: No me funciona, me sale el mensaje de: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Has coloca async dentro de la función? Aquí tienes como sería. https://gist.github.com/Acelator/1512f0b1164607e601e18910c4e28026#file-user-js

Comment: Ya entendí, me estaba olvidando de eso, muchas gracias entendí también asincronia

Comment: Entonces ya funciona no?